# Chart.js graph with just two cordinates

Tags: charts, chart.js

I want to make a simple graph (just a line between two coordinates - (2,5) and (5,10)).

HtML

```
<canvas id="line" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

JavaScript

```
var lineData = {
  type: "line",
  data: {
  datasets: [{
        label: "Test",
        data: [{
            x: 2,
            y: 5
        }, {
            x: 5,
            y: 10
        }],
    }]
    }
  }
var line = document.getElementById('line').getContext('2d');  
new Chart(line).Line(lineData);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the code snippet below to render the chart correctly, or can visit the fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/pgv2jon3/1/

```
var lineData = {
  type: "line",
  data: {
  datasets: [{
        label: "Test",
        data: [{
            x: 2,
            y: 5
        }, {
            x: 5,
            y: 10
        }],
    }]
    }
  }
var ctx = document.getElementById('line').getContext('2d');  
new Chart(ctx, lineData);
```